# Batch File to Cross Ref Size and Rename 1300 Files that Lost their Names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I recently (accidentally) formatted a hard drive containing about 2000 important archived files. I used one data restore software that recovered the files but none of the names (All titled "LostFile_1, LostFile2...etc), and a 2nd software that recovered all of the names, but all of the files were corrupted and won't open.

We are in the middle of a code that cross-references the proper names from the corrupt files, and matches them to the missing name files (LostFile, etc) based on file size.

There are 2 folders, one named "RealFiles" that has the generic "LostFile" names but working files, and a 2nd folder "RealNames" that has the true names but broken files. We are cross-referencing file sizes that match, and pulling names from the "RealNames" files to rename the matching, uncorrupted "RealFiles".

**I am very close thanks to code by Ben Personick's comment below (thank you!), this almost does the trick, the log shows it is set to rename all files, but the output file in "Hard_Linked" only renames and creates a file for the first match.**

Code to rename and cross-reference (Credit Ben Personick):

```
  @(
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo off
    Set "_Src=C:\Path\Lost"
    Set "_Ref=C:\Path\Reference"
    Set "_Lnk=C:\Path\Hard_Linked"
    Set "_Dst=C:\Path\Renamed"
    Set "_Log=C:\Path\Rename.log"
  )

 Set "_J=0"
 For /F "Tokens=*" %%A in ('
   Dir /A-D /B /OSE "%_Src%"
 ') Do (
   Set "_SrcFile!_J!=%%A"
   Set /A "_J+=1"
 )

 Set /A "_J-=1"

 Set "_I=0"
 For /F "Tokens=*" %%A in ('
   Dir /A-D /B /OSE "%_Ref%"
 ') Do (
  Call ECHO.Rename: "%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" - To: "%%A"
  Call ECHO.Rename: "%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" - To: "%%A">>"%_Log%"
  REM Comment the next line to stop maiing hardlinks
  CALL MkLink /H "%_Lnk%\%%A" "%_Src%\%%_SrcFile!_I!%%"
   REM Un-comment the next line to move files to final folder renamed
  REM CALL MOVE /Y "%_Src%\%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" "%_Dst%\%%A"
   Set /A "_I+=1"
  )

 (
   Endlocal
   Exit /b
 )
```

Log:

```
Rename: "LostFile_1.file" - To: "Correct Name 1.file"
Rename: "LostFile_2.file" - To: "Correct Name 2.file"
Rename: "LostFile_3.file" - To: "Correct Name 3.file"
Rename: "LostFile_4.file" - To: "Correct Name 4.file"
Rename: "LostFile_5.file" - To: "Correct Name 5.file"
```

Result in Hard_Linked folder:
LostFile1 properly created and renamed the proper name, but not 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: So do you have a file (or 3-4 lines of it) that you can share with the real filenames and sizes?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Sure! All are video files. One of the corrupted files names is "Football Test Run.mp4" at a size of 14,163 kb. The file that works but has the wrong name is LostFile_Mov_123120128.mov . I only need the first part of the file replaced, not the extension portion.

Comment: I need to see how the list actually looks, with commas or spaces, whether the name comes first on the line or the length comes first, whether the name is in double quotes, whether the size is in bytes or sometimes in kB or sometimes MB...

Comment: @Compo Actually, StackOverflow is a website where people can ask for assistance and solutions including "is there a code that can do this?", which I have read a few thousand threads on others asking assistance in web development, and that's exactly what I'm doing. This is not for a business, app or software, it is a one time use for personal files. Go be a troll somewhere else.

Comment: @MarkSetchell it is actual files, there is one folder with about 1300 files that are unopenable but with names intact, and another folder with 1300 files that are openable but "LostFile". There isnt an actual text list of the files though.

Comment: @Chris, if you _do not know how to write .bat files or how to reference the different elements necessary in cmd_, you should search read learn and try it before asking here. Even if you fail to learn it due to not understanding something, you'd explain that in your question, **_I read this, and tried this but it didn't seem to work, I expected this to happen, but all that happened was...I thought it meant..., Can someone please help me to clarify?_**, seems more like you're not just asking _If someone is able to come up with a short script that I can drop in the folder, click on..._!

Comment: I will. I have edited the question, can you please remove the On Hold status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this is actually fairly easy in cmd.

But lets take it a step further instead of all in one dir, stick both in two dirs.

Also, I would suggest running wirh a log of what will be renamed first for review and/or copying the files to a 3rd directory for review to be certain you got the results you wanted.

So as you are unfamilliar with cmd/batch scripting, I want to note that we have a few options on how to iterate the files, most comonly `for,` `for/F`, and `Forfiles` are common go-to for looping over files, sometimes with a `DIR` cmd in a `for /F` alternatively with a `WMIC` file list (although, thankfully WMIC is finally getting depricated in favor of Powershell).

If You want to just assume that each file will be correct based off size and sizes match exactly and are not duplicated and you're fairly certain of this, then using a `dir` cmd to sort by size will be a pragmatic method to do the matching quickly

If more needs to be done on matching then a `for` or `forfiles` loop would be a better alternative

To save space in this Process instead of copying we can create hard links, then you can test they alll work,  assuming they do, you can delete the hard links and use the Move command torename them.

```
  @(
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo off
    Set "_Src=C:\Ren\Lost"
    Set "_Ref=C:\Ren\Reference"
    Set "_Lnk=C:\Ren\Hard_Linked"
    Set "_Dst=C:\Ren\Renamed"
    Set "_Log=C:\Ren\Rename.log"
  )

 Set "_J=0"
 For /F "Tokens=*" %%A in ('
   Dir /A-D /B /OSE "%_Src%"
 ') Do (
   Set "_SrcFile!_J!=%%A"
   Set /A "_J+=1"
 )

 Set "_I=0"
 For /F "Tokens=*" %%A in ('
   Dir /A-D /B /OSE "%_Ref%"
 ') Do (
   Call ECHO.Rename: "%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" - To: "%%A"
   Call ECHO.Rename: "%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" - To: "%%A">>"%_Log%"
   REM Comment the next line to stop maiing hardlinks
    CALL MkLink /H "%_Lnk%\%%A" "%_Src%\%%_SrcFile!_I!%%"
   REM Un-comment the next line to move files to final folder renamed
    REM CALL MOVE /Y "%_Src%\%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" "%_Dst%\%%A"
   Set /A "_I+=1"
  )

 (
   Endlocal
   Exit /b
 )
```

---

I'll explain this a bit next but have to jet atm.

Just had a chance to get back ad while I can't spend the time to explain now due to a busy day at work, I fixed one error, by adding `Set /A "_I+=1"`, which is why it was not advancing the value of the test file each time.

---

Here is example Output as I had time to run it to make sure it works, and it's working exactly as expected for me.

```
Y:\>C:\Ren\RenameScript.cmd
Rename: "SomethingOld.ext1" - To: "ReferenceFileCorect_A_Unique1.ext1"
Hardlink created for C:\Ren\Hard_Linked\ReferenceFileCorect_A_Unique1.ext1 <<===>> C:\Ren\Lost\SomethingOld.ext1
Rename: "SomethingOld.txt" - To: "ReferenceFileCorect_A_New_name.txt"
Hardlink created for C:\Ren\Hard_Linked\ReferenceFileCorect_A_New_name.txt <<===>> C:\Ren\Lost\SomethingOld.txt
Rename: "SomethingOld3.txt" - To: "ReferenceFileCorect_A_ThirdName.txt"
Hardlink created for C:\Ren\Hard_Linked\ReferenceFileCorect_A_ThirdName.txt <<===>> C:\Ren\Lost\SomethingOld3.txt
```

This message:`Hardlink created for C:\Ren\Hard_Linked\ReferenceFileCorect_A_Unique1.ext1 <<===>> C:\Ren\Lost\SomethingOld.ext1` is the output of MKLink, if you are not seeing that in the CMD prompt then you likely have not run the CMD script in an administrative cmd prompt.

We can add code to the script to call PowerShell and re-launch itself in an administrative cmd prompt, but it would less muddy the waters if you do that directly for testing as that wasn't part of your original Q.

### So I would like to take a minute to explain what the script is doing and why for you so you can go forward yourself:

```
 SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

We are turning on Delayed Expansion, to allow us to easily evaluate the contents of the variables inside of a for loop by referencing them with `!_var!` instead of `%_Var%`, technically we can get away without this, if any of your filenames have `!` in them, we should disable this and re-write it a bit, if not then it's fine.

```
 ECHO OFF
```

I am stopping the script from echoing every line it is doing so we have less cluttered output.

Setting the variables sees self-explanatory

this allows us to easily loop variables and update their contents within the loop without using CALLs.

```
 Set "_J=0"
 For /F "Tokens=*" %%A in ('
   Dir /A-D /B /OSE "%_Src%"
 ') Do (
   Set "_SrcFile!_J!=%%A"
   Set /A "_J+=1"
 )
```

Here I am using `DIR` to quickly sort the files by Their Size and Extention, and return just the filenames.  DIR is extremely fast at doing this so it's preferable if you are doing a little sorting rather than matching the files using IF compares later.

The Option `/A-D` ignores directories `/B` will only output the file name (since we aren't recursing)  `/OSE` -- `/O` is "Order By" the Options `S` and `E` sort by size then file extention, so even if two files have the same size, if their extension differs the sort order will be the same.

This is all placed inside a `For /F` Loop which is a way to parse the output of a command, we use `"Tokens=*"` to make sure we take all non white-space returned ad place it in the variable.

IN the `DO ()` section we are incrementing a temporary variable `_J` and then creating a pseudo array in memory by creating variables that use the value of `_J` to hold the value of each file returned from the DIR command to the loop. `Set "_SrcFile!_J!=%%A"`

```
 Set "_I=0"
 For /F "Tokens=*" %%A in ('
   Dir /A-D /B /OSE "%_Ref%"
 ') Do (
   Call ECHO.Rename: "%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" - To: "%%A"
   Call ECHO.Rename: "%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" - To: "%%A">>"%_Log%"
   REM Comment the next line to stop maiing hardlinks
    CALL MkLink /H "%_Lnk%\%%A" "%_Src%\%%_SrcFile!_I!%%"
   REM Un-comment the next line to move files to final folder renamed
    REM CALL MOVE /Y "%_Src%\%%_SrcFile!_I!%%" "%_Dst%\%%A"
   Set /A "_I+=1"
  )
```

We now loop the output of `DIR` again, this time on the Reference directory, and since the file set is the same, the order will be the same as the process in the first loop iteration, and only the names returned will differ (IE exactly what we want.)

Within the `DO ()` here we receive each result from `DIR`, Echo it to the CLI, Echo it into a Log using the `>>` redirection, and then Create Our Hard Links, or Rename the files using MOVE (if you un-comment the line by removing "REM)

(Note, if we were going to echo and log multiple lines I would have used a CALL to a sub-function to do this so there wouldn't be duplicate lines, however since it is only the one time I decided to just leave it as is)

Since the order is the same I know that whatever iteration we are on, we don't have to do any compare ops (slow) so long as we're fairly sure no dupes exist.

I chose to create HARD links here because there is going to be almost no overhead in creating them, and they allow you to do live tests to see exactly how the files seem to be before moving them to rename them, which is the best of all worlds)

*Having Run into Similar situations before myself and working them by hand (as a kid) I can tell you I wish I knew this trick 20 years ago to save time and disk in testing out files.*

`MKLINK` is a godsend for these sorts of things.  Now you have the speed of a MOVE op, but the benefit of a copy to make sure you don't accidentally rename them and cause a problem in your real source files.

If you are satisfied with the results, you can Delete all of the Hard Links, `REM` out the Hard Link Creation, and Un-Comment the MOVE line which should rename them all the same way permanently.  Then just be sure to delete your reference files at the end so you don't accidentally keep the bad file you want to save.

This is

Comment: Very close! I've tested with 2 demo files each in Lost and Reference, and it looks like it is renaming the same file Twice. In the log: Rename: "LostFile1_23456.mov" - To: "Real File Name 1" (this is correct), then the next line is: Rename: "LostFile1_23456.mov" - To: "Real File Name 2" (it is ignoring LostFile2). In the Hard_Linked folder it is showing LostFile properly renamed as Real Name 1, but Lostfile 2 has no record (although it correctly matches exactly in size to Real Name 2). Aside from file paths I have the code exactly as is above, so it seems maybe a wrong loop somewhere?

Comment: @Chris  Glad to help, the issue was minor, I did not increment the value of I the way I did with J.  That can happen when you write batch scripts on your mobile phone in the AM. XD  `Set /A "_I+=1"`

Comment: Geez, no problem bud, you are a real lifesaver here! Now I see in the log it is set to rename all files (Long list and all looks correct), but the output in "Hard_Linked" only shows the first file in the log list actually created and renamed! If you can detect what may be wrong (maybe in the MkLink line) feel free, I will do my best to 'reverse engineer' the code and try to figure out what these things do in the meantime :)

Comment: Try running it in an administrative command prompt, probably you ran it that way in an earlier iteration, and not in a newer one, Hardlinks can only be created in an administrative command prompt.

Comment: You had it right with your last fix, by chance some of the files i tested had weird chars in the filenames and didnt want to copy. Renamed and it worked. Thank you sir!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Chris, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

- Build a (pseudo) array with the size[123] as name and file name as value by iterating the real file names.
- Then iterate the LostFiles and check if a matching size exists and rename.

Tested and enhanced:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\07\09\SO_56946186.cmd
@Echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "RealNames=A:\Test\RealNames\*"
Set "RealFiles=A:\Test\RealFiles\LostFile_*"

for %%N in ("%RealNames%") do set "size[%%~zN]=%%~fN"
:: set size
for %%F in ("%RealFiles%") do if defined size[%%~zF] (
    for %%n in ("!size[%%~zF]!") do (
        Ren "%%F" "%%~nn_Fixed%%~xn" && Del "%%~fn"
    )
) else (
    echo no matching size[%%~zF] for %%F
)
```

<s>The rename command is only echoed, remove the echo to **do** the rename.</s>

Dir listing before:

```
> gci A:\Test\* -Recurse
    Verzeichnis: A:\Test\RealFiles

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-11-13     07:52              0 LostFile_1
-a----       2016-11-18     17:12            878 LostFile_2
-a----       2018-01-27     16:17           9811 LostFile_3
-a----       2016-12-10     19:53            435 LostFile_4
-a----       2019-05-27     23:50              2 LostFile_5
-a----       2019-05-27     23:50              7 LostFile_6
-a----       2017-08-18     17:05            985 LostFile_7
-a----       2017-03-21     16:24           1086 LostFile_8
-a----       2017-03-21     16:24           3002 LostFile_9

    Verzeichnis: A:\Test\RealNames

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-11-13     07:52              0 1099511627776
-a----       2016-11-18     17:12            878 Choose-CUI.ps1
-a----       2018-01-27     16:17           9811 ConvertTo-Expression.ps1
-a----       2016-12-10     19:53            435 Enum-SpecalFolders.vbs
-a----       2019-05-27     23:50              2 ESC.bin
-a----       2019-05-27     23:50              7 ESC.hex
-a----       2017-08-18     17:05            985 Get-Date.cmd
-a----       2017-03-21     16:24           1086 Get-High20Proc.ps1
-a----       2017-03-21     16:24           3002 High20Proc.html
```

And after running the batch:

```
> gci A:\Test\* -Recurse

    Verzeichnis: A:\Test\RealFiles

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-11-13     07:52              0 1099511627776_Fixed
-a----       2016-11-18     17:12            878 Choose-CUI_Fixed.ps1
-a----       2018-01-27     16:17           9811 ConvertTo-Expression_Fixed.ps1
-a----       2016-12-10     19:53            435 Enum-SpecalFolders_Fixed.vbs
-a----       2019-05-27     23:50              2 ESC_Fixed.bin
-a----       2019-05-27     23:50              7 ESC_Fixed.hex
-a----       2017-08-18     17:05            985 Get-Date_Fixed.cmd
-a----       2017-03-21     16:24           1086 Get-High20Proc_Fixed.ps1
-a----       2017-03-21     16:24           3002 High20Proc_Fixed.html
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! I tried this (setting proper paths of course) but the .bat file just runs and closes with no echo before exiting. Ben's code below is 95% there but one final bug, if you would like to have a look maybe you can determine what's missing from yours or his?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, my ***answer*** had missing double quotes, I also changed it to delete the RealName file if the rename was successful.